# What are all the Properties of the WordPress Post Object?

Tags: variables

*(**Moderator's note:** Title was originally "What are all the variables in the wordpress post object?")*

Does anyone know the variables that are stored in the WordPress Post object?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Post object is mostly queried row of `wp_posts` database table with some extras. It is easy to dump content of one and see:

```
object(stdClass)
      public 'ID' => int
      public 'post_author' => string
      public 'post_date' => string
      public 'post_date_gmt' => string
      public 'post_content' => string
      public 'post_title' => string
      public 'post_excerpt' => string
      public 'post_status' => string
      public 'comment_status' => string
      public 'ping_status' => string
      public 'post_password' => string
      public 'post_name' => string
      public 'to_ping' => string
      public 'pinged' => string
      public 'post_modified' => string
      public 'post_modified_gmt' => string
      public 'post_content_filtered' => string
      public 'post_parent' => int
      public 'guid' => string
      public 'menu_order' => int
      public 'post_type' => string
      public 'post_mime_type' => string
      public 'comment_count' => string
      public 'filter' => string
```

Comment: Did you get this from var_dumping a post? Just wondering why mine had ancestors acessible as well. More comprehensive than me anyway, +1.

Comment: Yep, `var_dump()` ftw. :) For the record mine was xdebug-enhanced version, but that only affects presentation. Don't know about `ancestors` field, never really encountered it used.

Comment: It should be noted that most of the time the best practice is to access properties through the API functions, rather than interacting directly with the $post object.

Answer (score 4):

If you are referring to what you can access using `$post` (retrieved using `var_dump`):

- ID
- post_author
- post_date
- post_date_gmt
- post_content
- post_title
- post_excerpt
- post_status
- comment_status
- ping_status
- post_password
- post_name
- to_ping
- pinged
- post_modified
- post_modified_gmt
- post_content_filtered
- post_parent
- guid
- menu_order
- post_type
- post_mime_type
- comment_count
- ancestors
- filter